# code coverage doesn't reach void set function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Code Coverage doesn't reach some lines of codes even though I'm testing them. :(

Here is bind.ts decorator and [[NOT COVERED]] code coverage tag I created. Currently the set(value) is not covered by the test even though I'm covering it.

```
type Descriptor<T> = TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>;

export default function bind<T = Function>(
  target: object,
  key: string,
  descriptor: Descriptor<T>
): Descriptor<T> {
  ...
    set(value: T): void {
    [[22-NOT COVERED]]  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    [[23-NOT COVERED]]    throw new Error('Unable to set new value to decorated method');
    [[24-NOT COVERED]]  }
    [[25-NOT COVERED]]  Object.defineProperty(this, key, { ...descriptor, value });
    },
  };
}
```

bind.spec.ts
My strategy is to create new class Component and test its context on call

```
class MockClass extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  @bind
  getProp(): string {
    const { propName } = this.props;
    return propName;
  }

  @bind
  getState(): string {
    const { stateName } = this.state;
    return stateName;
  }

  @bind
  setProp(value: string): void {
    this.state = { stateName: value };
  }
}

...

describe('bind', () => {
  const mockState = {
    stateName: 'stateName',
  };

  const mockProp = {
    propName: 'propName',
  };

  const mockClass = new MockClass(mockProp, mockState);

  ...

  it('should have called it once', () => {
    expect(mockClass.getProp()).toBe(mockProp.propName);
  });

  it('should have called it in setState', () => {
    expect(mockClass.setProp('newState')).toBe(undefined); <<<- This can cover 22-25??
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncovered setter is code that would be exercised if you set a value of the class property. You don't have any test code that does this. You're only *getting* a property named `setProp` then calling it. The fact that the property has "set" in its name may be confusing matters.

Your test code would have to do something like this to test the setter of the decorator:

```
mockClass.props.otherPropName = 'blah';
mockClass.getProp = function() {
  const { otherPropName } = this.props;
  return otherPropName;
};
expect(mockClass.getProp()).toEqual('blah');
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob. But I'm getting this erorr on `otherPropName`:

Comment: Cannot assign to 'otherPropName' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

Comment: The getter overwrites the property, making it read-only: `Object.defineProperty(this, key, { ...descriptor, value });`